# What causes this pattern in wood knots

Tags: magnetic-fields, everyday-life, material-science

I am see these interesting looking lobes emanating out of knots of wood:

[image]

The shape almost looks like magnetic field lines. It's probably just coincidence but I wonder if there is a similar PDE that describes both.

[image]

What causes this shape in wood knots?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is (k)not a question about physics.

Comment: @JohnRennie strongly disagree. This is materials science and pattern formation

Comment: @JohnRennie appreciate the pun though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the tree grows, it puts out side branches from its main trunk. the point of origin of the side branch develops into a knot, and the annual growth rings that get added onto the trunk and branches then bend around the knot to accomodate its presence.

Then, when you slice the tree trunk into boards with flat sides or peel the trunk to make plywood veneer, the slice cut then intersects the tree rings in a variety of odd ways especially around the knots, and interesting patterns then show up in the boards.

This is an unpredictable process, which makes each board cut from a given trunk display a unique grain pattern. I do not know of any equations which have been used to describe the process, but in geometrical terms the cut path represents a *section* fixed in a plane relative to the axis of the tree trunk, and that section then contains a mapping of the tree ring structure onto the section.